# Why is gcloud failing to access all Google APIs and printing out HTML inside a Compute Engine VM?

Tags: gcloud

When I SSH into a server, running `gcloud compute instances list` should list the instances but instead I see the following in the terminal:

```
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{
margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images
/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-de
coration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;pad
ding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-r
epeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/br
anding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/
images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-rati
o:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-we
bkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/0.1/meta-data/service-accounts/default/acquire?scope=http
s%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%20htt
ps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute</code> fro
m this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I have the correct scopes added to the machine so this should work. It's also peculiar that a command line application tool is printing out HTML (´・ω・｀)

Trying to access any other Google API from the VM also fails.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix this? I'm getting similar errors for `gcloud compute instances list` and others despite full scopes too.

Comment: @JamesWalker Unfortunately, no. I got in touch with tech support but haven't gotten a response back in a while. They asked if it would be possible for me to delete and recreate the whole project lol. I created a separate service account and put the key in all of the servers I create, effectively making instance scopes unusable. I have to do authentication on GCE instances as if it were on a machine outside GCP. It's very disappointing.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yeah I found that using another service account works, but I can't figure out how to easily automate it in a bash script (what I'm trying to do).

Comment: I'm going to try creating a new project now and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, working now. Fortunately my app is not live yet so moving everything to a new project won't be too difficult. Hopefully Google are looking into this,  it's a very annoying problem :/

Comment: @JamesWalker Cool. Luck you! lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gcloud is trying to authenticate, but failing to do so, because the service account on the vm is damaged in some way.  The error should probably be cleverer in such a circumstance.  I will relay it to the teams responsible for the tool.

Comment: could you explain? We hit the same issue when running through REST API. Turns out if we use a specific account, then the error occurs. If we use account "default" when launching instance, then things start to be working. And the service account we specify by email is pretty much working and valid on its own. The issue is only obtaining the token, obtaining email and scopes works fine.